# Сериализуемый класс с динамическим набором полей

Tags: c#, сериализация

Дайте наводку как реализовать класс который можно будет сериализовать в такой XML:

```
<mcbmsg>
  <head>
      <ServiceName>SED</ServiceName>
      <RequestUID/>e6e9af2a-686e-0a88-9c22-0cc2b5250be8</RequestUID>
      <ReplyUID/>
      <ReferenceUID/> 
      <RequestDT>2022-07-21T12:12:12</RequestDT>
      <Sender>IBSO</Sender>
      <Receiver>TESSA</Receiver>
   </head>
   <body>
      <CardID>13C85CBF-320A-4C1A-89EE-31119ED564EF</CardID> 
      <IsAccepted>1</IsAccepted>
   </body>
</mcbmsg>
```

Проблема лишь в том что состав полей body постоянно меняется.
т.е. секция head не меняется, а начинка body может быть разная.

пробовал реализовать через Idictionary но выдает ошибку при сериализации

```
namespace Shared.Model.Integration
    {
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "head")]
        public class Head
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ServiceName")]
            public string ServiceName { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequestUID")]
            public string RequestUID { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReplyUID")]
            public string ReplyUID { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "ReferenceUID")]
            public string ReferenceUID { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "RequestDT")]
            public string RequestDT { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Sender")]
            public string Sender { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Receiver")]
            public string Receiver { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Body")]
        public class Body
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "Fields")]
            public Dictionary<string, object> Fields { get; set; }
        }

        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Msg")]
        public class Msg
        {
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "head")]
            public Head Head { get; set; }
            [XmlElement(ElementName = "body")]
            public Body Body { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

помогите с реализацией body плз.

Comment: Уже все давно JSON используют для сериализованных данных, какой смысл у вас в XML?

Comment: Требование заказчика.

Comment: И что значит динамический? Есть большой набор для body, но не все там отображается, либо вообще что угодно может быть? Если второе, то как тогда это десереализуется потом? Либо есть несколько наборов полей, но в зависимости от параметра в head используется какой-то конкретный набор?

Comment: Условно есть стандарт запроса и ответа в котором Head, в частности набор полей head остается неизменный но вот состав полей body в зависимости от типа запроса меняется. Я думал сделать класс в котором будут все возможные поля и его заполнять в зависимости от необходимости но косяк в том что пустые поля тоже сериализуются пустыми значениями.

Comment: XmlSerializer не поддерживет Dictionary, потому что KeyValuePair является read-only, а это не вписывается в логику устаревшего сериализатора. То есть проехать со словарем можно только на своих собственных костылях - [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3671259/12888024). Но я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону полиморфизма и насоздавал моделей с фиксированным набором полей под каждый тип данных - [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5998713/12888024). А еще проще пошатать требования к проекту и использовать JSON.

Comment: Спасибо, да я пошел путем полиморфизма. Буду под каждый случай наследовать отдельный класс.

Comment: Я планировал в своём ответе упомянуть полиморфизм (XmlInclude и всё такое), но ответ и так уже слишком большой. Если что, зовите. Способ хороший и, вероятно, самый правильный.

Comment: Я понимаю, что в вопросе код чисто для примера, но всё же не могу не посоветовать использовать `Guid` вместо `string` для свойств `*UID`, и `DateTime` для `RequestDT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу можно решить по-разному.

Создаём класс со всем набором возможных свойств. Навешиваем на эти свойства атрибут `System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue`. И задаём там значение по умолчанию, которое не будет сериализоваться.
У ссылочных типов дефолтное значение `null`.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

```
public class Body
{    
    public string CardID { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int IsAccepted { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int X { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Если задано:

```
Body = new Body
{
    CardID = "13C85CBF-320A-4C1A-89EE-31119ED564EF",
    IsAccepted = 1,
    // свойства X и Y равны дефолтному значению (0)
    // поэтому в XML их не будет
}
```

Результат будет:

```
<body>
  <CardID>13C85CBF-320A-4C1A-89EE-31119ED564EF</CardID>
  <IsAccepted>1</IsAccepted>
</body>
```

Если задано:

```
Body = new Body
{
    X = 3,
    Y = 4
}
```

Результат будет:

```
<body>
  <X>3</X>
  <Y>4</Y>
</body
```

---

Другой вариант - использовать свойства с суффиксом `Specified`.
XmlSerializer учитывает значение этих свойств в процессе работы. Если оно задано `true` - свойство с совпадающим именем будет сериализовано, иначе - нет.
Сами такие свойства помечаем атрибутом `XmlIgnore`.

```
public class Body
{
    public string CardID { get; set; }
    public int IsAccepted { get; set; }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool CardIDSpecified { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool IsAcceptedSpecified { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool XSpecified { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool YSpecified { get; set; }
}
```

Задавая эти свойства можно гибко настраивать список сериализуемых значений:

```
var body = new Body();
//...
body.CardIDSpecified = false;
body.IsAcceptedSpecified = false;
body.XSpecified = true;
body.YSpecified = true;
```

P.S. Также можно использовать методы с префиксом [ShouldSerialize](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/defining-default-values-with-the-shouldserialize-and-reset-methods?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)